# How to get profile picture from "profile album" of Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get **profile picture** from **profile album only**.

I know how to get profile picture directly from userId and i know how to get the photos of album.

**the problem is -**

I need to get all the photos from profile album and need to set the **profile picture on first position**.
If i get the profile picture directly from userId and after that i place the profile album photos then the profile picture will **repeat twice** because it's in album too.

So, i need some solution like i'll **identify** the **profile picture** from **profile album**.

any link,tutorial,suggestion,idea will be great help.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
This will definitely help you.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=albums.fields(name,photos.fields(name,picture,source))"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          //NSLog(@"result %@",result);
                          NSString * anImage;
                          NSArray* albums = result[@"albums"][@"data"];
                          NSUInteger index = [albums indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                              return [obj[@"name"]  isEqualToString: @"Profile Pictures"];
                          }];

                          if (index != NSNotFound) {
                              NSDictionary *profileImages = albums[index];
                              NSDictionary *photos = profileImages[@"photos"];
                              NSArray *data = photos[@"data"];

                              for (NSDictionary *picture in data) {
                                  NSString *date = picture[@"created_time"];
                                  NSString *id = picture[@"id"];
                                  NSString *pictureUrl = picture[@"picture"];
                                  NSString *sourceUrl = picture[@"source"];

                              }

                          }
                      }];
```

Comment: from this how i know which one is profile picture from album ?

Comment: This requests gets all the albums, and then from trial and error; all profile images were in around 3rd album (2nd index), you can try the same.

Comment: it's not working at all. what if i have only one album ? and i already said that i know how to fetch the album. i need to identify the profile picture from the album.

Comment: @sam You were right, that wasnt the right approach, so I did a little digging in my code and came up with this, I'm sure it'll help you.

Comment: this is also not giving me the actual profile picture but for your try i removed negative point. if you found the profile picture from the specific profile album then please tell me.

Comment: I did, Its giving me my profile pictures. You want to retrieve you profile pictures album right?

Comment: it gives me all the images of profile pictures but how i find if there are 5 profile photos in album then i ll get the current profile picture.

Comment: Observing the images that I am retrieving, Its always the first object. Current profile image.

Answer (score 2):

The reply above (below once I added my reply) helps me. I upvote, the updated solution for SDK V4:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]  initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"albums.fields(name,photos.fields(name,picture,source,created_time))"}]
                          startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              //NSLog(@"result %@",result);
                              NSString * anImage;
                              NSArray* albums = result[@"albums"][@"data"];
                              NSUInteger index = [albums indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                  return [obj[@"name"]  isEqualToString: @"Profile Pictures"];
                              }];

                              if (index != NSNotFound) {
                                  NSDictionary *profileImages = albums[index];
                                  NSDictionary *photos = profileImages[@"photos"];
                                  NSArray *data = photos[@"data"];

                                  for (NSDictionary *picture in data) {
                                      NSString *date = picture[@"created_time"];
                                      NSString *id = picture[@"id"];
                                      NSString *pictureUrl = picture[@"picture"];
                                      NSString *sourceUrl = picture[@"source"];

                                  }

                              }
                          }];
```